# Is there a way to have a producer member function?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Using coroutines 1.3-RC2, I want to do the following:

```
class Foo {
    fun getPrimes() = produce {
        var i = 0
        while (true) {
            if (i.isPrime()) {
                send(i)
            }

            i++
        }
    }
}
```

But it complains that `produce` can't be used due to receiver mismatch. I could wrap `produce{}` in `runBlocking`, and it compiles, but it blocks.

So, how to achieve this producer pattern, such that client code can run `myFoo.getPrimes().consumeEach(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`produce` requires a coroutine scope to run in. You can pass a scope:

```
class Foo {
    fun getPrimes(scope: CoroutineScope) = scope.produce {
        var i = 0
        while (true) {
            if (i.isPrime()) {
                send(i)
            }

            i++
        }
    }
}
```

or, for example, mark `getPrimes` suspend and create a new scope:

```
class Foo {
    suspend fun getPrimes() = coroutineScope {
        produce {
            var i = 0
            while (true) {
                if (i.isPrime()) {
                    send(i)
                }

                i++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Though I'm still running into problems with this like I did with `runBlocking {`, where the calling code never gets the return value from `getPrimes`. Is there some nuance of how this is meant to be called?

Comment: Ahh, I got it to work. Changing from `coroutineScope { produce {` to `GlobalScope.produce {` has the desired behavior. Though if anyone can provide a good explanation, the next user to look at this may benefit :)